# Can't figure out what is wrong with "sort"

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to find out the smallest difference between two number in a sorted list so I wirte

```
 (define (smallest-dif lst)
   (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(empty? (rest lst)) (smallest-dif (rest lst))]
    [else (first (sort (cons (-(second lst) (first lst)) (smallest-dif (rest lst)))  <))]))
```

My example is: (smallest-dif '(5 500 505 600 650 10000))
but drracket tells me this:sort: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: '(50 . 9350)

I dont know what's wrong with my code. If I take out "first", the program can run properly. 
Can anyone help me? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s look at what this part of the code is doing:

```
(sort (cons (-(second lst) (first lst)) (smallest-dif (rest lst)))  <)
```

Say your list is `'(1 2 3)`. Let’s work out part of the evaluation by hand:

```
(sort (cons (- 2 1) (smallest-dif '(2 3))) <)
(sort (cons 1 (first (sort (cons (- 3 2) (smallest-dif '(2)))  <))) <)
(sort (cons 1 (first (sort (cons 1 empty) <))) <)
(sort (cons 1 1) <)
```

It’s trying to sort a cons cell, not a list, which is the contract violation it’s complaining about.

Comment: Aww, did'n think of that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it sorts and takes the first of every part of the list. You need to split them up into one that returns just the diffs and one that does the sorting and picking.

```
(define (diffs lst)
  (cond
    [(or (empty? lst) (empty? (rest lst))) empty]
    [else (cons (- (second lst) (first lst)) (diffs (rest lst)))]))
```

Then you can make your smallest-dif that uses that procedure in order to pick the smallest either the way you did with sorting and picking the first or you may use `min`.

Comment: @WorBlux Interesting, but how?

Comment: No I was wrong, it feels kind of like a fold, but you have two different ops, one on the first two of a list. (define (pairwise-fold-left pair-op op end-term lst) (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)) end-term (op (pair-op (fist lst) (second lst)) (pairwise-fold-left pair-op op end-term (cdr lst))))) (define (diffs lst) (pairwise-fold-left - cons lst)) something like that.

Comment: Looks nothing like a foldr/foldl. Folds accumulates ad this doesn't. It's just a generalisation of diffs and something one shoulddo when youdetect a patternin your code. BTW: If you could solve it with a foldr you could have solved it with a foldl which is constant space.